# Move files (listed in a .txt file) to another folder in Bash

Tags: bash, mv

I want to move the files listed in `files_to_mv.txt` to a new folder called `dest_dir/` using Bash. The files to move (photos with a `.jpg` extension) and the `dest_dir/` are located in the same folder.

The `files_to_mv.txt` file looks like this

```
photo_1.jpg
photo_2.jpg
photo_3.jpg
```

after `cd`-ing to the folder that contains the photos and destination folder, I have tried the following

```
while read file; do mv "$file" /dest_dir; done < files_to_mv.txt
```

and

```
for file in $(cat files_to_mv.txt); do mv "$file" /dest_dir; done
```

both of which give the error

```
mv: cannot stat 'photo_1.jpg'$'\r': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'photo_2.jpg'$'\r': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `dos2unix files_to_mv.txxt`

Comment: Just in case anyone else has this issue. I solved it by using Notepadd++ to write the .txt file after changing the "EOL Conversion" (under the "Edit" menu) to UNIX. This writes a .txt file with UNIX style line endings.